Any way to iterate through animation data and identify fcurves for pose bones?
I am looking for a way to iterate through the animation data for an armature and add a modifier to the pose bones.    I cannot figure out how to go from an individual bone back to the fcurves that animate the bone.
I know there is "Animation Data" which contains "Actions" which contain "Fcurves" which point to the bones using "data_path" properties, but I cannot identify how to go backward from the armature to the bone to the fcurve.   The bone does not contain anything that looks like it would point to animation data of any kind, and the fcurve does not contain anything which explicitly says "this animates bone X on armature Y."
It seems awkward and probably not correct to walk through all the fcurves and try to "interpret" which fcurve goes to a bone in a particular armature.    Is there a better way?
For bone constraints, there is a constraint collection in each pose bone:
constraints- Constraints that act on this pose channel
TYPE: PoseBoneConstraints bpy_prop_collection of Constraint, (readonly)    

But there does not appear to be anything similar for fcurve modifiers.
